# Oozie Xml Workflow Schema Validation error

Tags: hadoop, hbase, sqoop, oozie

When I run `oozie` in order to schedule `HBASE` through `sqoop` job incremental append.

I'm getting the following error:

```
<action name="sqoop-import">
    <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>

        <prepare>
            <delete path="${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/output-data/sqoop"/>
            <mkdir path="${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/output-data"/>
        </prepare>                                                                                                                               
        <configuration>                                                                                                                          
            <property>                                                                                                                           
                <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>                                                                                               
                <value>${queueName}</value>                                                                                                      
            </property>                                                                                                                          


        </configuration>                                                                                                                         

    <job-xml>/user/root/hbase-site.xml</job-xml>                                                                                                 
       <command>import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=test" --table test_plan_package --username sa --password pass 
       --incremental append --check-column testid --hbase-table test_plan --column-family testid</command>                            


  <file>/user/root/sqljdbc4.jar#sqljdbc4.jar</file>                                                                                                  
  <file>/user/root/hbase/hbase-client.jar#hbase-client.jar</file>                                                                                    
  <file>/user/root/hbase/hbase-common.jar#hbase-common.jar</file>                                                                                    
  <file>/user/root/hbase/hbase-protocol.jar#hbase/hbase-protocol.jar</file>                                                                          
  <file>/user/root/hbase/htrace-core3.1.0-incubating.jar#htrace-core3.1.0-incubating.jar</file>                                                      
  <file>/user/root/hbase/hbase-server.jar#hbase-server.jar</file>                                                                                    
  <file>/user/root/hbase/hbase-hadoop-compat.jar#hbase-hadoop-compat.jar</file>                                                                      
  <file>/user/root/hbase/high-scale-lib-1.1.1.jar#high-scale-lib-1.1.1.jar</file>   



    </sqoop>                                                                                                                                     
    <ok to="end"/>                                                                                                                               
    <error to="fail"/>                                                                                                                           
</action>                                                                                                                                        

<kill name="fail">                                                                                                                               
    <message>Sqoop failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>                                                       
</kill>                                                                                                                                          
<end name="end"/>
```

I try various portals and came to know that problem is with xml schema version `0.2` and it need to be upgraded to 0.4 in workflow.xml.

Could anyone provide me the steps to upgrade the xml version to 0.4 in oozie.

Answer (score 0):

modify your job-xml above the configuration and there no need to upgrade to xml 0.2 to xml 0.4 directly exit 0.4 because in oozie-site.xml we have xsd file for that the error your getting because of Job-xml should be place above the configuration.
and check the jars according to version and modify the workflow.xml